# How can I invoke an Action and output it's result, as if it were a "user control"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

In my `_Layout.cshtml` file, I'd like to invoke something like this:

```
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left-wrapper" class="box">
            @Html.Action("FreeThisWeek", "Products")
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my ProductsController file:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult FreeThisWeek()
{
    //Some code that fetches the data and builds the model.
    var model = BuildFreeProducts();
    return View(model);
}
```

If I try to run this code, I get a `StackOverflowException` because the Action returns the View() which asks for the Layout, which runs the Action which returns the View(), and so on.

Understandable, but how do I accomplish this which correct code?

Where do I write the View that compounds this data model with the HTML I write?

Answer (score 2):

try returning `PartialView("yourview",model)` . Make sure the view you are returning does not use this page as a layout. you can specify that by using `@{Layout=null}` at the top of the view you are returning.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the View inside your `FreeThisWeek` Action and inside the View you are using the _Layout again. So it become recursive.

Go to your `FreeThisWeek` View and set Layout as null

```
@{
   Layout=null;
}
```